# Somehow import Django object inside a js script

Tags: javascript, django

I would like to access a django object inside a js script. In other words, I want the output of `{{ contract.request.customer.fax }}` with something like `var fax = {{ contract.request.customer.fax }}`, but it did not work.

My code is not being rendered by Django - presumably it is in a separate JavaScript file, not in a Django template. Is it a good way to to such thing without needing to pass the value into your JS from my actual template itself.

What is the correct solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think there are two ways to tackle this.  First, you can embed that value in a data- attribute of an element in your html and then retrieve it in javascript using something like the jQuery .data() function.  For example, you add a data-fax attribute to a DIV tag with id "contact" and then use var fax = $("#contact").data("fax).  Or you can build a server-side api that renders the fax number as part of a JSON object (use the django jsonrequest method) and then call it using and ajax call in your javascript.

Comment: @MikeC Could you build a complete answer? I may accept your answer. If you could make some good example, it could be appreciate.

Comment: where is the file? in the static folder or templates? if you keep the js file in templates folder that will work, or else you can include the js file  a html file . that could help

Comment: What server-side programming language/framework are you using?